# How long would it take to run out of “space” in storytelling for an average sized galaxy?

Tags: planets, galactic

I know that the average galaxy has over 400 billion stars and most stars have planets around it so it seems foolish to think the writers would ever run out of planets. It’s just for the suspension of my belief; Star Wars adds new planets constantly all the time and eventually it’s going to get confusing when there is so much “real estate” and not enough galaxy to physically hold it. On Wookieepedia, someone used AutoWikiBrowser to get an approximate amount of 5,291 planets so far covered in Star Wars storytelling since 1977

What could I tell my headcanon in the future when Star Wars runs out of space for new planets? I may be a bit silly and the number of 5000+ is just a drop in the bucket for a galaxy but I want to be prepared nonetheless.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's cross posted from [sci-fi & fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271957/will-the-star-wars-galaxy-run-out-of-space-for-planets). Please don't do that, it clutters the network with duplicates. Besides, you should edit the question there to get it reopened as per their site rules. If the answer given there does not satisfy your question, you can leave a comment to ask the answerer for clarification. You should also bear-in-mind that questions regarding third-party worlds are off-topic here.

Comment: You run out of space when the writers want to use overpopulation and lack of space/resources as a plot element.

Answer (score 3):

This is the subject of the [Drake Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation). A typical result says there should be about 15 million civilizations for us to find in Milky Way. If you took the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy approach and gave each planet two words, you could fill thousands of novels. You aren't going to find a limitation there.

From another perspective, you are asking the question, "How many stories are there to tell?" The number of possible permutations of even the most common tropes is greater than the number of atoms in the universe, and would take longer than the heat death of the universe to tell.

So, overall, no, there is no rational limit.

Comment: Earth: "Mostly harmless"